# UncategorizedMongoDbException when invoking the method from test case

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using embedded mongo for UT. and getting UncategorizedMongoDbException. when I use collation on aggregation.
But, the actual operation is working fine when tested with postman.

I am using mongodb atlas for development

> ---------Exception cause---------------Command failed with error -1: 'unrecognized field 'collation'' on server localhost:33181. The full response is { "waitedMS" : { "$numberLong" : "0" }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unrecognized field 'collation'" }

Code:
aggregate function is written and adding option to it.

```
aggregation =
aggregation.withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().collation(Collation.of("en")
                .strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.primary())).build());
```

Comment: What is the actual code defining `aggregation`, as in the actual "pipeline" construction. All you are showing is the addition of the "options" through the builder. Also, the error says "localhost", so it's **Not Atlas** because that is remotely hosted. Check your locally installed MongoDB instance for it's version. You are probably running a server prior to version 3.4 locally. And prior to that version "collation" is not supported. But also really should be ignored when correctly entered into the "options".

Comment: MongoDB is supporting the operation locally as well as on atlas. but for mocking data in test cases I am using embedded mongo. i  suspect that embedded mongo do not support full feature of the actual MongoDB I am using

Comment: The flapdoodle thing? There actually is no such thing as "embedded mongo" and what that package is calling "embedded" is simply another binary installation of mongodb which gets started during unit tests. AFAIK, It is an Old version. Certainly older than 3.4 as I last saw it. It's a bit of a **lie** actually to call that "embedded". It's actually just "clickbait" ( for the embedded term of course ), and frankly quite pointless as you're better off just having a normal local install and using that. I've seen that package cause more problems than it's worth, and IMHO it should be avoided.